# Airflow DockerOperator create Mount objects dynamically

Tags: airflow, dockeroperator

Is there a way to create the Mount objects of DockerOperator dynamically so that I can use the filesystem connection stored in Airflow db? I don't want to change the dag code if the connection changes.

At the moment I need to hardcode the paths like this

```
            incoming_path = "/incoming/XYZ"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
            output_path = "/output_path/ABC"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
            input_mount = {"source": incoming_path,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
                           "target": incoming_path,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
                           "type": "bind"}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
            output_mount = {"source": output_path,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
                            "target": output_path,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
                            "type": "bind"}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
            create_stuff = DockerOperator(                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
                task_id = f'create_stuff',                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
                user = 1234,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
                queue = 'default',                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
                image = 'image_name',                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
                api_version='auto',                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
                auto_remove=True,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
                mount_tmp_dir=False,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
                mounts=[Mount(**input_mount),                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
                        Mount(**output_mount)],                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
                environment={                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
                    'AF_EXECUTION_DATE': "{{ ds }}",                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
                    'AF_OWNER': "{{ task.owner }}",                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
                },                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
                command = f"do stuff",                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
                entrypoint='',                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
                docker_url='unix://var/run/docker.sock',                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
                network_mode='bridge'                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
            )
```

I tried to use the FSHook outside an Operator, but then it returns an empty string when I call

```
with DAG(...) as dag:
...
#THIS WORKS
@task
def task1():
    incoming_hook = FSHook('fs_incoming')
    incoming_path = incoming_hook.get_path()
    ...

#THIS RETURNS AN EMPTY STRING
incoming_hook = FSHook('fs_incoming')
incoming_path = incoming_hook.get_path()
```

So another phrasing for the question would be is there a way to get the path from the connection outside an Operator?

I'm using Airflow 2.4.1

Comment: Do you mean filesystem within Docker? DockerOperator uses [DockerHook](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-docker/stable/_api/airflow/providers/docker/hooks/docker/index.html#airflow.providers.docker.hooks.docker.DockerHook) which exposes the low-level Docker API client [`APIClient`](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html). Can you clarify what exactly you're trying to do, and what you mean by "is there a way to get the path from the connection outside an Operator?"? What specifically do you mean by "path" here?

Comment: I want to mount filesystem paths to the container that I run using DockerOperator. The first code sample works fine, it's just that I need to hard code the paths incoming_path and output_path in the dag file. The second code snipplet doesn't work, get_path just returns an empty str. I'm not familiar with DockerHook, I need to check it out.

Comment: Would an [Airflow Variable](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts/variables.html) make more sense? If `incoming_path` needs to be truly  hardcoded, what's wrong with the current implementation in the top block of code you shared?

Comment: Variable might be alright, it's just that then it would be an exception in the logic of using FileSystem Connections. In the above example I need to hard code the path when I define the Mount objects. When I use the path in tasks, I can just retrieve the path inside a task code using the hook and changes in the connection are automatically propagated to the task. In the above example DAG would not work if I would edit the connection.

Comment: I don't understand the need to use a filesystem connection instead of a string if you're ultimately just passing a string to the `DockerOperator`'s `mounts` parameter.

Comment: I use the same path in multiple tasks in different dags and Connection seems like a good way to manage that. This example is just 5% of the actual dag code. I have also two separate Airflow instances for dev and prod.

Comment: From [the docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/connection.html): "Airflow’s Connection object is used for storing credentials and other information necessary for connecting to external services.". Having a string path doesn't really fit the intention for a Connection object. As I mentioned in my answer, this is a use case better suited for a Variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you just need to share a common string between multiple DAGs, I'd recommend either using an [Airflow Variable](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/variable.html) or using some kind of shared config file in your `/dags` directory. You can find more detail in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52006063/how-to-work-with-configuration-files-in-airflow).

---

Forcing the use of a hook here is unnecessary as [Airflow Connections](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/connection.html) are "used for storing credentials and other information necessary for connecting to external services". I don't believe that applies here, but if you *did* need to use a Connection, you wouldn't need a Hook; you could just use [the Connection API](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/_api/airflow/models/connection/index.html) to access Connection properties.

[Hooks](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts/connections.html#hooks) give you additional functionality for actually interacting with external systems. [FSHook](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/_api/airflow/hooks/filesystem/index.html) would allow you to actually interact with a filesystem rather than just share the `path` value across DAGs.